# How to find surface area of a wing by integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, physics

I have a question about aerodynamics. I came across that the wing area of ​​an airplane is calculated with this formula, but I can't calculate the integral. Even if the plane wing area is not calculated like this, can you please solve it step by step, it is very important to me. [Wing planform geometry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F6Mk.png) Do not get hung up on the unnecessary details in the picture(or you could If you wish)
$$\frac{\left(\int_{-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{b}{2}}c\ dy\right)}{\int_{-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{b}{2}}\ dy}b$$ Where c represents the chord length at a given distance y from the centerline. And $$b=11$$ $$c_{t}=1.63$$   $$c_{0}=1.12$$ unit

Comment: Did you realise that $b$ includes the fuselage? I'd have assumed if you wanted to do anything useful you need to know the width of the fuselage here.

Comment: width of the fuselage is 1.2 unit and wingspan is 11 unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the wing-length isn't given, you don't know $c(y)$; all you can say from the figure is:

$$c(y)=\cases{\frac{b+2y}{b-w}c_0+\frac{-2y-w}{b-w}c_t & $\frac{-b}{2}\le y\le\frac{-w}{2}$ \\
c_0 & $-\frac{w}{2}<y\leq \frac{w}{2}$\\
\frac{b-2y}{b-w}c_0+\frac{2y-w}{b-w}c_t & $\frac{w}{2}<y\le\frac{b}{2}$} $$

where $w$ is your unknown fuselage width.

Decide on $w$ and the integral is routine.

Taking the integrals over only the wings (excluding the fuselage),

$$\begin{align}\frac{2\int_{\frac{w}{2}}^{\frac{b}{2}}\left(\frac{b-2y}{b-w}c_0+\frac{2y-w}{b-w}c_t\right)dy}{2\int_{\frac{w}{2}}^{\frac{b}{2}}dy}(b-w)
&=\frac{\frac{\frac{b^2}{2}}{b-w}c_0+\frac{\frac{b^2}{2}-bw}{b-w}c_t}{b-w}(b-w)-\frac{\frac{bw-\frac{w^2}{2}}{b-w}c_0-\frac{\frac{w^2}{2}}{b-w}c_t}{b-w}(b-w)\\
&=\frac{\frac{b^2}{2}+\frac{w^2}{2}-bw}{b-w}(c_0+c_t)\\
&=\frac{b-w}{2}(c_0+c_t)
\end{align}$$

Of course our wingshape was assumed trapezoidal, and so this formula could have been written without the integration

Comment: Thank You so much

Comment: @Dazai If this answers your question feel free to "accept" the answer

Comment: It's a little late but I have a question. I don't get how did you find the equations for the values /2<≤/2 and /2≤≤/2

Comment: It's a point-to-point linear interpolation equation (the simplest of which can be written $(1-t)x_0+tx_1$) where $t\in[0,1]$